# Why does lpstat not show my print job?

Tags: 20.04, printing

After printing a document via *cups*, `/var/log/cups/access_log` contains the following log entry (and the printer *did* print):

```
"POST /printers/Brother HTTP/1.1" 200 70947 Print-Job successful-ok
```

However, the print job is not listed when querying via *lpstat*:

```
# lpstat -W all -u user
# lpstat -v
device for Brother: ipp://printer.test.:631/ipp/port
```

Why is *lpstat* not showing me the successfully executed print job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the user filter, the output does list all print jobs, including completed ones:

```
# lpstat -W all -u
Brother-1  unknown  70606  2020-10-26T11:46:15 UTC
```

*cups* does not publish the print jobs owners name, hence filtering by the name does not work.